# Multithreaded scene changes in Qt3D

Tags: multithreading, qt3d

I am encountering a strange issue trying to perform multi-threaded updates to the tranformation matrices of QEntities in a Qt3D scene.

The scene consists of about 2000 entities that need to be animated by updating their transformation matrices. The illustrative code below works perfectly:

```
QHash<Qt3DCore::QTransform *, QMatrix4x4> transforms;
// ... populate with the transformation matrices of ~2000 CylinderMesh entities

for(auto&& transform: transforms.keys())
    transform->setMatrix(transforms[transform]);
```

In order to speed this up, I thought I would make it multi-threaded as follows:

```
QtConcurrent::blockedMap(transforms.keys(), 
    [transforms](Qt3DCore::QTransform *t){
        t->setMatrix(transforms[t]);
});
```

This code, however, crashes somewhere inside the Qt objects (stack trace below).

I don't discount that there's an error elsewhere in my code but given that it works fine in a single-threaded way, I'm starting to question whether it is safe to make multithreaded changes to a Qt3D scene?

Here's the stack at crash time:

```
1   ntdll!RtlRegisterSecureMemoryCacheCallback                                                     
2   ntdll!RtlZeroHeap                                                                               
3   ntdll!EtwLogTraceEvent                                                                          
4   ntdll!RtlRegisterSecureMemoryCacheCallback                                                      
5   ntdll!EtwLogTraceEvent                                                                          
6   ntdll!RtlReAllocateHeap                                                                         
7   ntdll!RtlReAllocateHeap                                                                         
8   realloc                                                                                         

9   QArrayData::reallocateUnaligned                                         qarraydata.cpp      224

10  QTypedArrayData<Qt3DCore::QNode *>::reallocateUnaligned                 qarraydata.h        117

11  QtPrivate::QPodArrayOps<Qt3DCore::QNode *>::reallocate                  qarraydataops.h     259

12  QArrayDataPointer<Qt3DCore::QNode *>::reallocateAndGrow                 qarraydatapointer.h 208

13  QArrayDataPointer<Qt3DCore::QNode *>::detachAndGrow                     qarraydatapointer.h 194

14  QtPrivate::QPodArrayOps<Qt3DCore::QNode *>::emplace<Qt3DCore::QNode *&> qarraydataops.h     174

15  QList<Qt3DCore::QNode *>::emplaceBack<Qt3DCore::QNode *&>               qlist.h             856

16  QList<Qt3DCore::QNode *>::append                                        qlist.h             433

17  QList<Qt3DCore::QNode *>::operator+=                                    qlist.h             681

18  Qt3DCore::QChangeArbiter::addDirtyFrontEndNode                          qchangearbiter.cpp  47

19  Qt3DCore::QNodePrivate::propertyChanged                                 qnode.cpp           338 

20  Qt3DCore::QNodePrivate::propertyChanged                                 qnode.cpp           330 
... <more>
```

Comment: Why are you using a blocking map? Have you tried using `QtConcurrent::mapped`? Maybe there's a deadlock somewhere (which wouldn't directly explain the error but maybe it's related). I guess the updates could happen non-blockingly, right?

Comment: I made it blocking in order to isolate the problem to that statement. Using map(...) instead produces the same crashing result (not mapped(..) because I don't care about the return value). The problem can be solved by surrounding the call to QTransform::setMatrix(...) with a mutex, but that completely defeats the purpose of parallelizing the process.

Comment: Might that you got into an issue with the Qt3D's threadding mechanism :/ And having a worker thread that executes setting the matrix on all transforms is no option? I.e. it has to happen in parallel? I'm just asking because then your UI would still be responsive. Or you use a threadpool with multiple threads. I remember that I didn't have much luck using QtConcurrent either.

Comment: Of course, that's how it's done right now. I'm simply attempting to make the change happen faster so animations are smoother.

Comment: One thing you could try is to create a single `QParameter` which stores either the rotation quaternion or the rotation matrix and add this same parameter instance to the materials of all your objects. I'm not sure if you can share parameters between materials but I think so. But then you need your own material/shader implementation where you use this new parameter. It's not soo difficult though.

Comment: Or another idea where I'm also not sure if it works (due to object sharing issues): You could have the actual meshes (and materials for that matter) added to an entity which also has a transform that is solely responsible for the shared rotation. This transform is the same instance for all your objects. The placement in your world is handled by a transform on a parent entity. You could also try adding both transforms to the same entity, the shared rotation transform first I guess. Then you only need to set the rotation matrix once.